# How to print a list, dict or collection of objects, in Python

Tags: python, list

I have written a class in python that implements `__str__(self)` but when I use print on a list containing instances of this class, I just get the default output `<__main__.DSequence instance at 0x4b8c10>`. Is there another magic function I need to implement to get this to work, or do I have to write a custom print function?

Here's the class:

```
class DSequence:

    def __init__(self, sid, seq):
        """Sequence object for a dummy dna string"""
        self.sid = sid
        self.seq = seq

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __str__(self):
        return '[' + str(self.sid) + '] -> [' + str(self.seq) + ']'

    def next(self):
        if self.index == 0:
            raise StopIteration
        self.index = self.index - 1
        return self.seq[self.index]
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, you need to use [`__repr__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__). A quick example of its behavior:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __str__(self):
...             return '__str__'
...     def __repr__(self):
...             return '__repr__'
...
>>> bar = Foo()
>>> bar 
__repr__
>>> print bar 
__str__
>>> repr(bar)
'__repr__'
>>> str(bar)
'__str__'
```

However, if you don't define a `__str__`, it falls back to `__repr__`, although this isn't recommended:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __repr__(self):
...             return '__repr__'
...
>>> bar = Foo()
>>> bar
__repr__
>>> print bar
__repr__
```

All things considered, as the manual recommends, `__repr__` is used for debugging and should return something `repr`esentative of the object.

Comment: Is it worth conforming to what the manual says "If at all possible, this should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value (given an appropriate environment)." So something like DSequence(1, 'GTTAC')?

Comment: Ok, I also found this q for that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452300/python-object-reprself-should-be-an-expression
Thanks for your help.

Comment: BTW, why do containers use repr() to print elements? Should I use it too for my own containers?

Answer (score 1):

Just a little enhancement avoiding the + for concatenating:

```
def __str__(self):
  return '[%s] -> [%s]' % (self.sid, self.seq)
```