# Python repr for classes

Tags: python

As the [Python 2 documentation on `__repr__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) states:

> If at all possible, this (i.e. `__repr__`) should look like a valid Python expression that *could be used to recreate an object with the same value* (given an appropriate environment).

So how come **builtin `__repr__` for classes** does not act accordingly to that guideline?

#### Example

```
>>> class A(object):
...   pass
>>> repr(A)
"<class 'A'>"
```

To meet the guideline, the default `__repr__` should return `"A"`, i.e. generally `A.__name__`. Why is it acting differently? It would be extra-easy to implement, I believe.

---

#### Edit: The scope of 'reproduction'

I can see in the answers that it is not clear in the discussion what `repr` should return. The way I see it, the `repr` function should return a string that allows you to reproduce the object:

1. *in an arbitrary context* and
2. *automatically* (i.e. not manually).

**Ad.1.** Take a look at a built-in class case (taken from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452300/python-object-repr-self-should-be-an-expression)):

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>>
>>> repr(date.today())        # calls date.today().__repr__()
'datetime.date(2009, 1, 16)'
```

Apparently, the assumed context is as if you use the basic form of import, i.e. `import datetime`, because if you would try `eval(repr(date.today()))`, `datetime` would not be recognized. *So the point is that `__repr__` doesn't need to represent the object **from scratch**.* It's enough if it is unambiguous in a context the community agreed upon, e.g. using direct module's types and functions. Sounds reasonable, right?

**Ad.2.** Giving an impression of how the object could be reconstructed is not enough for `repr`, I believe. Helpfulness in debugging is the purpose of `str`.

#### Conclusion

So what I expect from `repr` is allowing me to do `eval` on the result. And in the case of a class, I would not like to get the whole code that would reconstruct the class from scratch. Instead, I would like to have an unambiguous reference to a class visible in my scope. The `"Module.Class"` would suffice. No offence, Python, but `"<class 'Module.Class'>"` doesn't just cut it.

Comment: Actually, it would need to return something like `type("A", (), {})`: code that can generate a class equivalent to `A`. As mgilson points out, it's difficult to build an *expression* (note that classes are typically defined by a `class` *statement*) that creates a class.

Comment: This would actually quite tricky to implement as well as rather useless and confusing.

Comment: @larsmans Depends how deep you'd go to define an object. I'm not talking about reproducing a class from scratch. See the edit, please.

Comment: @JanuszLenar: ah, yes, if that's what you want, it's actually quite simple and reasonable.

Answer (score 3):

Consider a slightly more complicated class:

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo=3
```

`repr` would need to return something like

```
type("B", (object,), { "__init__": lambda self: setattr(self, "foo", 3) })
```

Notice one difficulty already: not all functions defined by the `def` statement can be translated into a single `lambda` expression. Change `B` slightly:

```
class B(object):
    def __init__(self, x=2, y, **kwargs):
        print "in B.__init__"
```

How do you write an *expression* that defines `B.__init__`? You can't use

```
lambda self: print "in B.__init__"
```

because `lambda` expressions cannot contain statements. For this simple class, it is already impossible to write a single *expression* that defines the class completely.

Comment: Python 3 solves this by making `print` a function, so no obstacles remain for a new `repr` on classes (although `eval` probably works even in Python 2 ;)

Comment: I was ignoring the `print` function in Python 3 :), but there are other statements (`if`, `while`, `try`, etc.) that you would need to handle. `eval` also expects an expression (or a code object); you may be thinking of `exec`. But `__repr__` isn't supposed to be a robust dynamic code generator; it's a convenience function that should be somewhat usable if reasonably possible.

Comment: `exec` is a statement. With `eval`, you can actually set variables: `eval('locals().__setitem__("ham", "spam")')`. `while` can be made an expression with a fixed-point operator, `if` has an expression form... I'm fully aware that I'm speaking great evils :)

Comment: We're turning this question into "How can I rewrite my class in Lisp?" :)

Comment: @chepner You're totally right about the lambda misfit for the general solution. As Martijn says, if I were to represent the whole class fully, I would rather pickle it. I think the purpose of `repr` on a class is pinning down the class' name. Do you agree on that?

Answer (score 2):

Because the default `__repr__` *cannot* know what statements were used to create the class.

The documentation you quote starts with *If at all possible*. Since it is not possible to represent custom classes in a way that lets you recreate them, a different format is used, which follows the default for all things not easily recreated.

If `repr(A)` were to just return `'A'`, that'd be meaningless. You are not recreating `A`, you'd just be referencing it then. `"type('A', (object,), {})"` would be closer to reflecting the class constructor, but that'd be a) confusing for people not familiar with the fact python classes are instances of `type` and b) never able to reflect methods and attributes accurately.

Compare the output to that of `repr(type)` or `repr(int)` instead, these follow the same pattern.

Comment: It's worth noting that we're talking about the class itself, not about an instance of the class.

Comment: Notice that OP isn't trying to represent an *instance* here ... Python does know (in many cases at least) the source code used to create the class.

Comment: It's true.  Creating a class via `type(name,subclasses,cls_dict)` would be pretty hard to gather all of that information into a meaningful string to recreate it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters You are right that the result of `repr` might be hard to read. But it's not aimed to be readable; it's meant to be able to reproduce the object. So regarding a), I wouldn't care. Want a readable string? Use `str`.

Comment: @JanuszLenar: *I* want a string that gives me a good idea of what it is I am debugging instead. If you want to have a serialization format, use pickle or marshall instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Good point. I'm editing the question to pin down requirements for `repr`.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older question, but I found a way to do it.

The only way I know to do this is with a metaclass like so:

```
class A(object):
    secret = 'a'

    class _metaA(type):
        @classmethod
        def __repr__(cls):
            return "<Repr for A: secret:{}>".format(A.secret)
    __metaclass__ =_metaA
```

outputs:

```
>>> A
<Repr for A: secret:a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since neither `"<class 'A'>"` nor `"A"` can be used to re-create the class when its definition is not available, I think the question is moot.

Comment: The question stays valid even if the answer is 'it's impossible to implement'.